# O que é -webkit-transform? Para que serve?

Tags: css, css3, front-end

Então, direto eu encontro nos CSSs isso -webkit-transform, mas não tenho ideia do que é ou para que serve e deus também não sabe me responder:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ficaria eternamente grato se alguém pudesse me explicar ou me passar algum lugar em que eu possa ler sobre isso. Obs.: Sei ler inglês.

Obrigado pela atenção!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) é uma ferramenta de CSS moderna. Ela permite fazer zoom, dar perspectivas ou rodar elementos.

O prefixo `-webkit-` quer dizer que só os browsers que têm estrutura do `webkit` é que vão usar/ler/aplicar essa regra.

Um exemplo que está na página da MDN e que faz rodar 5 graus um elemento `div`:

```css
#rotate1
{
    height:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate1">
<pre>
    height:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
</pre>
</div>
```

E um exemplo de *zoom* com rotação:

```css
div { 
    background:#fcf8b3;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    margin:100px;
    padding:10px;
    width:330px;
 
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition:transform 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

div:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    /* CSS3 */
    -webkit-transform:scale(3) rotate(-15deg) skew(-5deg, 30deg);
       -moz-transform:scale(3) rotate(-15deg) skew(-5deg, 30deg);
            transform:scale(3) rotate(-15deg) skew(-5deg, 30deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
    Passa o mouse aqui se vês mal!
</div>
```

#### Nota:

Em relação à tua pesquisa no Google tens de ter em conta que `-` no inicio de uma busca quer dizer: "quero resultados **sem** a palavra -xxxxxx".
Deves procurar com aspas, [assim: `"-webkit-transform"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22-webkit-transform%22&oq=%22-webkit-transform%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1575j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: +1 pela explicação sobre o Google, ia ser o meu comentário :)

Comment: cara, então eu não estava pesquisando nada? serio? KKKKKKKKK

Comment: Otima resposta!